# Website design using asp.net controls

Tags: html, asp.net

Is there any template site out there that has templates utilizing specifically:Asp.net button,asp.net gridview, asp.net textbox , asp.net menu, ajax control toolkit accordion, ajax control toolkit tabs.

Has applied sample css to show what can be done to make a web application look professional that i can then leverage?.
i have seen millions of templates that use css and html and images and they look good but none that are using asp.net controls.. and look good.
Any websites or an example of a descent site that utilizes these controls and makes them look realy good is welcome.
thanks,
Damo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up using css shading on all the varous divs like below,Radius border like below and finally CSS to my gridviews. Now it looks really good. I may change all the asp.net buttons to be image buttons and give them icons. 
thanks
damo

```
.TabControls

{




    margin-top:2px;  
    margin-bottom:2px;
    margin-right:2px;
    margin-left:2px;

    padding-top:2px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    padding-right:2px;
    padding-left:2px;     
    width: auto;

    border-width: 1px;  
    border-style: solid;  
    border-radius: 5px;

        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#99CCFF'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#9CF)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFF,  #9CF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */ 
    height:120px;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into .NET skins and themes. I'm pretty sure you can find samples on Microsoft's site or one of the MCPD exam prep books would help.

[.NET Skins and Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: ive tried all the googling to no avail. themes tell you how to apply one rather than give you an excellent professional example.

Comment: if you look at devexpress or telerik controls websites they have awesome examples but thats using their controls. what i need is similar for asp.net controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this site, he view code and executing

Linnk : http://quickstart.developerfusion.co.uk/quickstart/aspnet/